# Where should I put a 3rd js function and how to use it in .vue file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my vue app, I used a 3rd single js file contains a function, say `getXXX` looks like

```
(function(){function e(b,e,f)......&(window.getXXX=e)})();
```

I use this `getXXX` in my `A.vue`, if I just put this function inside `A.vue`, it works fine.

Now I'm thinking to put this long function to a single file, Where should I put a 3rd js function and how to use it in .vue file?

Comment: Put it in a file and `export` it. Then you can `import` it anywhere in your app

Comment: Put to `XXX.vue`, in `<script></script>` section?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function in the another single js file. And `export` that function like this,

`single-js-file.js` which contains your function

`export const getXXX = () => {
    console.log('that works!');
}`

And you can `import` it in the `A.vue` file like this,

`import {getXXX} from './path-to-that-single-js-file'`

And you can call that function in any of the life cycle hook in `Vue`

`created() {
   getXXX();
},`

Answer (score 0):

I would rather create a plugin for that (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html), to be more specific about my approach, you can import this javascript file in your html entry point, this will expose the API of this library to the `windows` object in the client, while you can use `window.xxx` is not a clean solution, so you can create a wrapper in the form of a plugin and just return the instance of this library as a global object.

Hope this helps,

Cheers.